# Why does my app crash when I click the floating action button?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-constraintlayout

My app crash when I am clicking the button, I don't know why it does that and I don't know how to fix it.

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            mLayout.addView(createNewEditText(mEditText.getText().toString()));
        }
    });

private EditText createNewEditText(String text) {
    ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout  = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.planlaeg_l);
    ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    mConstraintLayout.addView(et,0);
    set.clone(mConstraintLayout);
    set.connect(et.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, mConstraintLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 60);
    set.applyTo(mConstraintLayout);
    et.setText(text);
    return et;
}
```

Comment: Please show your stacktrace of the crash

Comment: How do I do that? (I am really new to all this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: If you want see the error try to add this `try{//your code}catch(Exception ee){Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ee.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()}`

Comment: did you attach a view to "mLayout" and  "mEditText" , like mLayout = findViewById(R.id.mLayout); ? I feel like it's a NullPointerException

Comment: If you are using android studio see the `Logcat` tab at the bottom of the screen. The red text is the stacktrace

Comment: I already has attached a view to mLayout and mEditText

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got an error like that "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first."

- Step 1:

  mConstraintLayout.addView(et,0);
- Step 2:

  return et;
- Step 3:

  mLayout.addView(createNewEditText(mEditText.getText().toString()));

**How to fix it:**

- Change logic add et view (in method createNewEditText / outside it)

Example:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createNewEditText(mEditText.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you want me to do because im very new to making apps.

Comment: @Jensen711 I edit my answer with an example solution, try it!

Comment: Unfortunately still crashes